# Container BoxDecoration

Tags: flutter, dart

На месте закругления выводится белый цвет от `Scaffold`.`Expanded` не помог. Есть ли метод, способ чтоб именно верхний контейнер заполнил обрезанные углы своим цветом?

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('image')), 
          ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Expanded` только про заполнение виджета во весь размер... Если вам ненужен `Expanded`, то уберите его.

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*И запомните: родитель задает параметры ребенку!*

---

### UPD

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('image')),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Исправил вопрос, в случае с картинкой как быть?

Comment: @AndreyKhan 1. Не изменяйте кардинально вопрос. (Один вопрос, один ответ) Если хотите дополнить вопрос, добавьте доп. информацию ниже... 2. Вы не описали чего хотите добиться для картинки.

Comment: @AndreyKhan дополнил ответ.